# Python syntax error when using boolean variable

Tags: python, syntax-error

new to development and have a rookie question.

I'm receiving a syntax error in the 2nd statement of this if block.
No idea why? Please help.

```
if engine_capacity <= 1600:
   rate=.25
if engine_capacity >1600 and =<2000:
   rate=.50
if engine_capacity > 2000:
   rate=.75
```

Comment: Because `=<2000` is not a valid expression; it's just a fragment. Also `=<` is not a valid operator. Perhaps you meant `1600 < engine_capacity <= 2000`. Though `elif` / `else` would be more elegant.

Comment: should be `if engine_capacity > 1600 and engine_capacity <= 2000:`

Comment: Or `if 1600 < engine_capacity <= 2000` for short

Comment: or better yet, `elif engine_capacity <= 2000`.

Comment: Thanks team. I'm definitely trying to be as elegant or accurate as possible. elif we'll try.

Comment: So this is my program, I definitely need some expert advice.

market_price = float(input('Enter the market price: '))
engine_capacity = float(input('Enter the engine capacity (number only): '))
manufacture_year = float(input('Enter the manufacture year: '))

initial_customs_amount = market_price * rate

if engine_capacity <=1600:
    rate=0.25
elif engine_capacity <=2000:
    rate=0.50

elif engine_capacity >2000:
    rate=0.75
depreciation_discount = market_price * ((2021 - manufacture_year) / 100) 
final_customs_amount = initial_customs_amount - depreciation_discount

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
engine_capacity = 2000
if engine_capacity <= 1600:
    rate = .25
if engine_capacity > 1600 and engine_capacity <= 2000: # <-- Should be <= not =<. You also need to type out the entire and statement, not just <= 2000
    rate = .50
if engine_capacity > 2000:
    rate = .75
```